# How can I set up a user/admin system using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, admin

I'm working on a project in which there's an ability for users to create their own playlists from a stored track listing provided from another table called Tracks on the server.

In order to do this i need to implement a user/admin system that defines whether the person is a user or an admin so that they are allowed to perform specific functions based on whether they are a user or an admin.

I'm very new to all this so i'm quite unsure on how to even start out doing this.

All i have currently is this table

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_User` (
 `Userid` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `Username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Forename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Age` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `Permissions` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Userid`)
  ) 
  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Can anyone provide me with some pointer on where to start with this?

Thank you.